# get location when pages loads

Tags: javascript, css, html, geolocation

I am Building a website useing HTML, CSS and Java script. I am wanting to get the location of the user when page loads. so they do not need to press a button. I was hoping some one can help.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation(){
 if (navigator.geolocation){
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 }
 else{
   x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
 }

function showPosition(position){
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: question is not clear, please elaborate more.

Comment: above the code when you open a page you have a button to press then a popup will ask you if the website can use your location. you say yes. i want to miss out first step so when you open site it then gos straight to ask you if website can use your location. just want to miss out the first button phase.

Answer (score 6):

Simply call the **`getLocation()`**

```
<script>
        var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation()
         {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
        }
        getLocation()
        </script>
```

​Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ES4TF/

Comment: As of Chrome version 50, the site have to be running https.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
 var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation()
         {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
        }
        getLocation()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update to the answer above for anyone wanting to do this in react without adding another script. Here is the code in ES2015 format for use with React etc, without needing to use any of the HTML stuff above. Just import the function. 
        Special thanks to the first post as mine is based off it .

```
        const showPosition = position =>{
              let loc = `Latitude:${position.coords.latitude}  logitude: 
              ${position.coords.longitude}`
               console.log(loc)
               return loc
             }

            const getLocation =  () => {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
               return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
              }
              return false
            }
```

then Just Import the function and Use It

If you want to get the state and zip you can use the google API. Here is the code to get geolocation and the sends to google and then gives you the state, address results. You will need to activate the google geolocation API.

```
//Docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding


  const getData = async (url) => {
         let res = await fetch(url)
         let json = await res.json()
         console.log(json);
         return json
         }

 const showPosition = async position =>{
        let loc = `Latitude:${position.coords.latitude}  logitude: ${position.coords.longitude}`
        let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&key={GOOGLE_API_key}`
        console.log(loc)

        let address = await getData(url)
        console.log(`results`,address)
        return address
        }

 const getLocation = async () => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
     return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
   return false
}
```