# Get location when page load, get request w coordinates?

Tags: javascript, get, geolocation

I have looked at examples on how to get a location when a page loads. I found this particularly question helpful: ([get location when pages loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194623/get-location-when-pages-loads)).

However, for testing purposes, I was hoping to build from this example and not display the coordinates, but rather craft a get request that includes the coordinates.

How would I accomplish this?

Best regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by waiting for the callback of the position to send the location to your API with `XMLHttpRequest`.

Here's an example:

```
if (navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendLocation);
} else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}

function sendLocation(position){
  var latlng = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      alert('Success');
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "uploadurl", true);
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(latlng));
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much! Just one follow-up, If I were to redirect the user to another URL once the post has been done, what operation would I use?

Comment: Just use the `window.location = 'url'` statement to change the page instead of the `alert('success')` function in my example.